# MySQL query to check for certain phrases (duplicate article, plagiarism)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysqli

Is there a way to check for multiple phrases in mysql?

I need to check if an article have a duplicate version stored in mysql.

This is the algorithm
I first create an array of sentences that needed to be check (removing all non-alpha-numeric characters)
Then Build the query (how?)
After I get the result I compare if 50% of the sentences are duplicate than I consider the article to be duplicate.
Articles in the table are stored with removed non-alpha-numeric characters.
Example:

```
iamdevelopingatooltocheckduplicatearticlesstoredinmysqldatabasehoweveriveencountered
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look into "Programming Collective Intelligence" to learn about these algorithms.  They have to do with grouping.